# Python: how do you handle variables and modules of the same name?

Tags: python

I'd like to use a module and store the result of calling one of it's methods into a variable with the same name as the module, but that would overwrite the module. **How to best handle this?**

**Example:**

```
from something.deep.library import users
users = users.get_users()
```

Obviously, it's not the best practice to overwrite the library with a variable. How can I best handle this? I've tried many things: some are ugly and some don't work.

```
# doesn't work
from something.deep import library.users
users = library.users.get_users()

# ugly and inconsistent across the codebase
from something.deep.library import users as library_users
users = library_users.get_users()
```

Comment: Why can't you name the variables something else?  Although I'm sure someone will post a way to handle this properly, having the same variables and modules names is a major code smell in my book.

Comment: What, do I have to name them `my_users`? `users_from_module`? `results`?

`users` simply makes sense.

Comment: That's just bad programming style.  If you really want to create confusing code, go ahead.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc: so what's your solution? What would you name it?

Comment: When you search for the usage of the library, you search for `users.`, but you'll miss all the places that use `userlib.`.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc: and that's the thing, I *don't* want to create confusing code, hence my question.

Comment: Rename your variable: `registered_users`, `logged_in_users`, `current_users`. Add some context to how that variable will be used.

Comment: Yes, that is the obvious solution, still hoping to get a more intuitive solution.

Comment: You want a more intuitive solution than naming your variables properly for their context?

Comment: The problem is that there's not much context to begin with, so I'd just have to make up a contrived name like `all_users` or `all_photos` which just doesn't sit right with me.

Answer (score 3):

[Python best practices](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules):

```
import library
users = library.users.get_users()
```

Using import - as notation is another good way, but imho first one is more clean and readable

Comment: Which is great for `library.users`. Not so great for `foo.bar.baz.quux.library.users`.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe you can not `import foo.bar.baz.bla.blah` in Python. You will have to use `from foo.bar.baz.quux import library` and then in code it is still `library.users.get_users()`

Comment: I wasn't using that as an import statement. I was making a point on the depth of the module.